# Binding List of List with For Loop From Data Set In C# Overwrite with Last Iteration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

C# MVC 4.I am Having a DataSet with several DataTables.When I loop over All the dataTable I am Consecutively binding an List< List < model > >.Here is my Code.Several hours has been spend on it.

While Loop iteration finished it shows "allMissingRigs"(which is a List < List < MissingRIG > > object) all the items overwritten with the last "missingRigs"(which is a List < MissingRIG > )

Is there any other way to Bind a List < List < Model > > ?

Whats wrong I am doing that Causes the Overwritten result with last Iteration value ??

```
        DataSet response =new DataSet();
        DataTable dtResponse = new DataTable();
        List<MissingRIG> missingRigs = new List<MissingRIG>();
        List<List<MissingRIG>> allMissingRigs = new List<List<MissingRIG>>()



       foreach (DataTable dt in response.Tables)
        {

        dtResponse = dt;
        missingRigs.Clear();


            foreach (var item in dtResponse.AsEnumerable())
            {
               missingRigs.Add(new MissingRIG( DataTableOperationHelper.GetStringValue(item, "date"),DataTableOperationHelper.GetStringValue(item, "shiftstatus"),
                                        DataTableOperationHelper.GetStringValue(item, "number")));
            }
        allMissingRigs.Add(missingRigs);


        }
```

Comment: When you debug your app, did you see different data for each iteration of dtResponse.AsEnumerable()? Since you said it was overwritten with the last list..

Comment: while debuggin its shows different data for each iteration.But when iteration finished i just found all the items has been overwritten with last iterated "Missing Rigs"...I would be thankful with any help

Answer (score 2):

The same instance of missingRigs is added each time. So when it's cleared and filled, it's always the same instance. To add a duplicate, you should create a new list inside the loop, instead of reusing the same list instance:

```
   foreach (DataTable dt in response.Tables)
   {
        dtResponse = dt;
        List<MissingRIG> missingRigs = new List<MissingRIG>();
       //missingRigs.Clear();
```